# What is a 'Screen' compared to a 'Page' in windows phone? And use it as a pop up login screen

Tags: windows-phone-8

I read that the screen is different from a page here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202911(v=vs.105).aspx

So what's the basic class of a screen? How to make use of it? Actually I wanna implement the same scenario in the article. I need a pop up screen whenever the authentication is required, any best practice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's no such thing as Screen in Windows Phone. The article you've mentioned refers to a Screen as to some UI construct, like UserControl, which can be embedded to the Page.

As for popup screen, you should use the [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class mentioned in the article, and just show or hide it when necessary. Alternatively, you could still create a separate page (e.g. PhoneApplicationPage instance) and navigate to it when there's a need for login operation.

Which approach you take (popup or separate page) depends on how you feel your app should behave in different situations. For example, if your app can without login in general, than I guess you can implement login view as a separate page. But if your app is basically defunct without login, you could implement popup and show it as soon as you determine that login is required.

As for best practices, if you're going to go with a Popup variant, I'd recommend you to create a UserControl, which has the Popup inside. That way you can encapsulate your login code (view + behavior) into a separate entity, to reuse it in different pages easily.

Comment: Thanks! If I prefer to login at the start screen, does it mean the MainPage has to be login page? Then the issue is when user touch back to MainPage, the logic will conclude one is logged in, it will always redirect to the main content page. How can this be fixed?

Comment: There are multiple approaches to solve this. I think that MainPage should not be the login page. Instead, when user launches the app, you check if he is logged in, and if not, navigate to login page. To check if user is logged in you could create some app-level object, and login page will modify it in case of successful login.